# CRM plugin to update attachment

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to have a plugin or workflow change the properties off a word document when it’s uploaded to an entities notes. For example, add the GUID of the letter activity to the word document attached to it?

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, any file (note) is stored in binary in crm db, so you would have to use a framework (maybe [aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) or somathing free) to load word document into some kind of object model and then change whatever you like.

Comment: How would I add a plugin to look at an attachment